# Showing that a linear mapping is invertible given a certain condition

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I want to make sure that what I did here is valid. My approach to show that $L$ is invertible was to just find the inverse. If $L^2 + 2L + I = 0$, then $L(L + 2I) = -I$ and $L(-L-2I)=I$. This would seem to imply that the inverse of $L$ is $(-L-2I)$. I don't have much experience doing these type of problems, and want to make sure that my approach is correct. If anyone has some other solutions feel free to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A matrix $A$ is invertible if and only if there exists a matrix $B$ such that $AB=I$.

You were correct to observe that $L(-L-2I) = I$, and this says that $-L-2I$ is the inverse of $L$.